# Second table of contents only for annexes

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I'd like to have in my report a table of contents from introduction to conclusion and another between the conclusion and the first annexe. This latter only for annexes :

```
- Table of contents
    - 1. Intro
    - 2. Chapter 1
    - ...
    - 20. Conclusion
- 1. Intro
- 2. Chapter 1
- ...
- 20. Conclusion
- SECOND TABLE OF CONTENTS
    - Annexe 1
    - Annexe n
- Annexe 1
- Annexe n
```

I know we can add annexes to the table of contents using :

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Annexes}
```

but is there a way to name a TOC like :

```
\tableofcontents{TOC1}
```

and use it to specify which one we want to add contents line :

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Annexes}{TOC1}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

yes `article` defines

```
\newcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \section*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    }
```

so you could define

```
\newcommand\tableofcontentsA{%
    \section*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{toca}%
    }
```

then use

```
\addcontentsline{toca}{chapter}{Annexes}
```

instead of

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Annexes}
```

This will store the headings in a filename with extension `.tocA` and input that file at the point where you use `\tableofcontentsA`. Note as there are `@` in the command names the definition needs to be in a package file or between `\makeatletter` `\makeatother`

If your annexes are using sectioning commands that are internally writing to the `.toc` file so that you can not easily just write to `toca` you can redefine the internal writing command to write to `toca` if passed `toc` as argument like so:

```
\let\oldaddtocontents\addtocontents

\def\addtocontents#1{%
   \def\tmpa{#1}%
   \def\tmpb{toc}%
   \ifx\tmpa\tmpb
      \def\tmpa{toca}%
   \fi
   \expandafter\oldaddtocontents\expandafter{\tmpa}}
```

In the standard classes (and most none standard ones) this will make all the sectioning commands write to `.toca` from the point of redefinition.

so a complete document

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
    \newcommand\tableofcontentsA{%
        \chapter*{\contentsname
            \@mkboth{%
               \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
        \@starttoc{toca}%
        }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{aa}
\chapter{aaa}

\appendix
\let\oldaddtocontents\addtocontents
\def\addtocontents#1{%
   \def\tmpa{#1}%
   \def\tmpb{toc}%
   \ifx\tmpa\tmpb
      \def\tmpa{toca}%
   \fi
   \expandafter\oldaddtocontents\expandafter{\tmpa}}
\tableofcontentsA

\chapter{bbaa}
\chapter{bbaa}

\end{document}
```

Comment: One has also to redefine `\appendix` so that `\chapter` issues `\addcontentsline{tocA}{...}{...}`

Comment: @egreg, Yes I wondered about that but the OP indicated he was calling `\addcontentsline{toc}` explicitly which means you can just change the call. I assumed teh class was using chapter* or something. I'll add a note to the answer.

Comment: Has the first argument of `\addcontentsline` be the same as `\@starttoc`? toca/tocA?

Comment: yes sorry it has to be the same and also you might need \chapter* rather than \section* if based on report or book rather than article. I just added a full working example

Comment: Thank you it works well. But I wanted to know how to change what is display when I use `\tableofcontentsA`. For the moment it's "Table of Contents" and I'd like "Table of Annexes"?

Comment: That's because I just copied the code:-) `\contentsname
` is what is making "Table of Contents" (it makes just "Contents" in book class) so you can just remove that and replace `\chapter*{\contentsname}` by `\chapter*{Table of whatever}`. If you are is using a different class, it is worth having a look at its sources and copying `\tableofcontents` from the class. In my initial answer I copied the one from `article.cls` which uses `\section*` in worked example at the end I used the one from `book` class which uses `\chapter*` but other classes might use fancier formatting that you could copy.

Answer (score 5):

The [titletoc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) package gives another possible (and shorter) solution:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\begin{document}

\startcontents
\printcontents{atoc}{0}{\chapter*{\contentsname}}

\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\chapter{Test Chapter Two}

\appendix

\startcontents
\printcontents{atoc}{0}{\chapter*{Table of Annexes}}
\chapter{Test Appendix One}
\chapter{Test Appendix Two}

\end{document}
```