# Number sections in secondary table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

I have a main document which contains a secondary documents table of contents. I'm using the example given in the first half of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55508/13835).

My secondary ToC doesn't use section numbering. I assume this is because I haven't defined the necessary bits for `toca`, but I'm not sure what those bits are.

#### How can I enable section numbering for my secondary table of contents?

Here's a minimal, working example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\tableofcontentsA{%
    \@starttoc{toca}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Main introduction}
\section{Example Document-2 Table of Contents}
% These are all defined in the same page, so disable page numbering    \cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}
\cftpagenumbersoff{section}
\cftpagenumbersoff{subsection}

\addcontentsline{toca}{chapter}{Introduction}
    \addcontentsline{toca}{section}{foo}
    \addcontentsline{toca}{section}{bar}
\addcontentsline{toca}{chapter}{baz}
    \addcontentsline{toca}{section}{barbar}

\tableofcontentsA
\section{Main Conclusion}

\end{document}
```

Here's what it produces:

[image: Example document]

I'd like to have something more like this:

```
1 - Main intro
2 - Example ToC
    1 - Intro
    1.1 - foo
    1.2 - bar
    2 - Baz
    2.1 - barbar
3 - Main Conclusion
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would go for it:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\tableofcontentsA{%
\indent
    \@starttoc{toca}%
}
\makeatother

\newcounter{tocachap}
\setcounter{tocachap}{0}

\newcounter{tocasect}[tocachap]
\setcounter{tocasect}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetocasect}{\thetocachap.\arabic{tocasect}}

\newcommand{\addchap}[1]{\refstepcounter{tocachap}
\cftaddtitleline{toca}{tocachap}{\indent\textbf{\thetocachap \hspace{1em}#1 \\[0.2em]}}{}
\par}

\newcommand{\addsect}[1]{\refstepcounter{tocasect}
\cftaddtitleline{toca}{tocasect}{\indent\thetocasect \hspace{0.5em}#1 \\[0.2em]}{}
\par}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Main introduction}
\section{Example Document-2 Table of Contents}

\addchap{Introduction}
\addsect{foo}
\addsect{bar}
\addchap{baz}
\addsect{barbar}

\tableofcontentsA
\section{Main Conclusion}

\end{document}
```

It produces this output:

[image: Output]

**Note 1** It is possible to create a command for the subsections.

**Note 2** Due to the redefinition of the section counter you should not use any chapter in your document because it may create a confusing main table of contents.